# cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘int*’ in initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

struct Array {
    int *A;
    int size;
    int length;
};

void display(Array *arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr->length; i++) {
        cout << arr->A[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

Array* merge(Array *arr, Array *brr) {
    Array *crr;
    crr->length = 0;
    crr->size = arr->length + brr->length;
    crr->A = new int[crr->size];
    int i, j, k; i=j=k=0;
    while(i < arr->length && j < brr->length) {
        if (arr->A[i] < brr->A[j]) {
            crr->A[k++] = arr->A[i++];
        } else {
            crr->A[k++] = brr->A[j++];
        }
    }
    for(;i < arr->length; i++) {
        crr->A[k++] = arr->A[i];
    }
    for(;j < brr->length; j++) {
        crr->A[k++] = brr->A[j];
    }
    crr->length = arr->length + brr->length;
    return crr;
}

int main() {
    Array arr1 = {{ 2, 6, 10, 15, 25}, 10, 5};
    Array arr2 = {{ 3, 4, 7, 18, 20}, 10, 5};
    Array *arr3;
    arr3 = merge(&arr1, &arr2);
    display(arr3);
}
```

Compiling this gives me this error. What is the right way to do this ?

```
$ g++ -o merge_arrays merge_arrays.cpp 
merge_arrays.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
merge_arrays.cpp:42:42: error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘int*’ in initialization
   42 |  Array arr1 = {{ 2, 6, 10, 15, 25}, 10, 5};
      |                                          ^
merge_arrays.cpp:43:41: error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘int*’ in initialization
   43 |  Array arr2 = {{ 3, 4, 7, 18, 20}, 10, 5};
      |                                         ^
```

I am initialising it at the same place I declare the `struct Array`. Isnt this the recommended way ? I read many stackoverflow answers recommending me to initialise arrays at the same place where I declare them. This is exactly what I do here. So a bit confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your merge function trys to access a pointer with no reference to any valid memory.

Comment: I used Jarod42 approach of using `Array arr1 = {new int[10]{ 2, 6, 10, 15, 25}, 10, 5};` but now I get segmentation fault at 
`crr->size = arr->length + brr->length;.`. Any hints what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: -> `Array *crr = new Array;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With owning raw pointer, it would be:

```
Array arr1 = {new int[10]{ 2, 6, 10, 15, 25}, 10, 5};
```

but your class doesn't respect rules of 3/5/0 and leak resource.

But standard already provides `std::vector` to handle collection and `std::merge`:

```
void display(const std::vector<int>&v) {
    for(int e : v) {
        cout << e << "\t";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

std::vector<int> merge(const std::vector<int>&v1, const std::vector<int>&v2)
{
    std::vector<int> res(v1.size() + v2.size());

    std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), res.begin());
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::vector arr1 = { 2, 6, 10, 15, 25};
    std::vector arr2 = { 3, 4, 7, 18, 20};
    auto arr3 = merge(arr1, arr2);
    display(arr3);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8add2935c21c73e4)

Comment: I didn't want to use anything from standard library so this works for me. But now I am facing another issue. I get Segfault at this line
`crr->size = arr->length + brr->length;`. What could be the reason ?

Comment: You have other issue as missing initialization of `crr` in `merge`.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42 this is the program that works for me.https://gist.github.com/agatsoh/19aa30586137a4767dba51f0c13ec2c6 Thanks for helping me and please dont delete the vector part.

Comment: final `delete arr3;` is missing. You don't use encapsulation with class Array, so you have to manually delete content in main instaed of destructor of the class...

Comment: yes true should have a final `delete arr3` there. I made the change in my gist. How can I achieve encapsulation using structs in C++? Using a class it is but obvious. I am just learning :)

Comment: `struct` and `class` only differ in their default visibility (`public` versus `private`). Once encapsulation of `Array` code is done, code might look like provided code with `std::vector`: No visible allocations from outside of `Array` internal.